# Can anyone fix a logic problem in my password generator in python

Tags: python

I am currently trying to learn some python and am following a bootcamp. I have been challenged to make a password generator before being shown how to do so. and I am having issues where the password generated is different to the password outputted to the user (only one character).

```
import random
# Password Generator
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']
genPassword = []
yourPassword = ""
print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n"))
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))
total = nr_letters + nr_numbers + nr_symbols

for n in range(0, nr_letters):
    randLetter = letters[random.randint(0, len(letters) - 1)]
    genPassword.append(randLetter)
for n in range(0, nr_symbols):
    randSym = symbols[random.randint(0, len(symbols) - 1)]
    genPassword.append(randSym)
for n in range(0, nr_numbers):
    randNum = numbers[random.randint(0, len(numbers) - 1)]
    genPassword.append(randNum)
print(genPassword)
for item in range(0, len(genPassword)):
    randomChar = random.randint(0, len(genPassword) -1)
    yourPassword += genPassword[randomChar]
print(yourPassword)
```

This is the out put I receive:

```
How many letters would you like in your password?
2
How many symbols would you like?
2
How many numbers would you like?
2
['s', 'g', '!', '#', '1', '5']
!g5s!g

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can see the third item in the list is being repeated twice for the generated password but I do not understand why. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that characters are being repeated is this:

```
for item in range(0, len(genPassword)):
    randomChar = random.randint(0, len(genPassword) -1)
    yourPassword += genPassword[randomChar]
```

Remember that `genPassword` is already a list of randomly-generated characters. You're taking random choices *from that already-generated list*. And you can choose the same number twice (and are likely to do so at least once).

May I suggest instead just doing this:

```
random.shuffle(genPassword)
yourPassword = ''.join(genPassword)
```

this way, you get all the exact already-generated characters, but in a random order.

Comment: Oh Iu understand, can't believe I couldn't see this before! Thank you for your help. I will now read up on shuffle and join as they are both new to me but I am glad I can now take advantage of them.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the random function, you should expect anything between 0 and len(genPassword) - 1.
This random number can repeat multiples times, and yet having a chance of being repeated every time.

Think as a dice, you can roll it 5 times and get three times the number 3, for example.

Try to use shuffle function from random package.
Delete the last for loop too.

```
    import random
# Password Generator
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']
genPassword = []
yourPassword = ""
print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n"))
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))
total = nr_letters + nr_numbers + nr_symbols

for n in range(0, nr_letters):
    randLetter = letters[random.randint(0, len(letters) - 1)]
    genPassword.append(randLetter)
for n in range(0, nr_symbols):
    randSym = symbols[random.randint(0, len(symbols) - 1)]
    genPassword.append(randSym)
for n in range(0, nr_numbers):
    randNum = numbers[random.randint(0, len(numbers) - 1)]
    genPassword.append(randNum)
    
random.shuffle(genPassword)
print(genPassword)
```